# Sequence of linear operators with bounded norm converges pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $U$ and $V$ be Banach spaces and $L(U,V)$ the space of bounded linear operators. Suppose $T_{n}\in L(U,V), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and the sequence $(||T_{n}||_{L(U,V)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. Then if $\lim_{n \to +\infty} T_{n}(u)$ exists for each $u$ in some dense subset $D\subset U$ then $T_{n}$ converges pointwise on all of $U$ to some $T\in L(U,V)$.

I tried to use the density of $D$ in $U$ to define $T_{n}(x)$ for general $x\in U$ by constructing a sequence $(u_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $D$ converging to $x$ and then setting $T_{n}(x):= \lim_{k\to +\infty} T_{n}(u_{k})$. But then I wasn't sure how to then obtain a limit  $T\in L(U,V)$. I wondered if maybe I needed to take the limit as $n\to +\infty$ but I wasn't sure if this made sense while I was taking the limit from $k\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u \in U$ and take  a sequence $(d_n) \subset D$ converging to $u$. Then $\|T_nu-T_mu\|\leq \|T_nd_k-T_md_k\|+2M\|d_k-u\|$ where $M=\sup_n \|T_n\|$. Choose $k$ such that $2M\|d_k-u\|<\epsilon /2$. Then choose $n_0$ such that $\|T_nd_k-T_md_k\| <\epsilon /2$ for $n, m \geq n_0$. We now get $\|T_nu-T_mu\|<\epsilon$ for $n, m \geq n_0$. Since $U$ is complete it follows that $Tu=\lim T_nu$ exists.
Linearity of $T$ is clear. It is also easy to see that $\|Tu\| \leq M\|u||$ for all $u$, so $T$ is bounded.